# Images from Parse Not Loading On iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, uiimageview

I got a `PFQueryCollectionViewController` populated by images, everything works fine on iOS 8.x.x and below, but when I run the application on iOS 9 using Xcode 7 Beta all the images are blank.

Here's the code I use to load images from Parse in the `PFQueryCollectionViewController`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    if([object objectForKey:@"image"] != NULL) {

        [[object objectForKey:@"image"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {                

            UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbnailImage];

            imageView.image = thumbnailImageView.image;

        }];

        }

     return cell;

}
```

and

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForCollection {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class"];   

    ...

    return query;
}
```

Comment: why would you take thumbnailImage through thumbnailImageView to  imageView?

Comment: I just ran into this same issue as well (with PFFile) and it looks like Parse is tracking updates to this on GitHub: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/12

Answer (score 10):

This is probably due to SSL requirements with iOS 9. Since Parse doesn't use HTTPS for files, they won't download correctly. Set the info.plist to include keys such as this, which turn off the SSL requirements...at your own risk, of course:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>files.parsetfss.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me - why doesn't parse document this somewhere?  I know there's an article about the switch to SHA-2 certs but this seems like a huge oversight...

Answer (score 2):

Find **Enable bitcode** in Build settings in respective target AND set it to **NO**

Answer (score 0):

@akaru's answer works great. Instead of adding an exception you can use [this](https://jcutrell.svbtle.com/quick-tip-serve-parse-files-via-https) trick to load parse images over `https`. Basically it means replacing `http://` with `https://s3.amazonaws.com/`. Like this example:

Http: `http://files.parsetfss.com/b05.../tfss-fa8-e541-...-jpg`

Https: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/b05.../tfss-fa8-e541-...-jpg`

Comment: Where do we make that change?

Comment: As per SO guidelines you should have extracted the relevant parts from the link to avoid exactly this, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: My bad, fixed it now.